# GCP: Download Blob object using Service Account, in local machine

Tags: python, cloud

```
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "path/to/service_account.json"

def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name,destination_file_name):
    from google.cloud import storage
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)
    print('Blob {} downloaded to {}.'.format(source_blob_name,destination_file_name))
```

> Error : raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
>   google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/test_role?projection=noAcl:
>   **nameofserviceaccount**@**projectid**.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to **bucketname**.

The service account has given the permission of Project Owner.

Comment: Did you add the service account in your project's IAM as a project owner? or did you assign a permission to the service account from the service accounts section. GCP does this weird thing if you don't add the service account as project owner in your project's IAM

Comment: Yes I added ServiceAccount as Project-Owner in IAM

Comment: That should be sufficient to make it work, are you sure you're using the correct service_account.json keyfile

Comment: Yes @AkshayApte I'm using the correct json file. Is there any problem with the program?